# Why latest verson of adaptivecards not comppilable anymore for SPFX integration?

Tags: adaptive-cards, spfx

I was using adaptivecards for my spfx solution. It was working fine for me and now I wanted to upgrade my packages since I was using deprecated versions. I upgraded my solution with latest version of adaptivecards and adaptivecards-templating and adaptivecards-fluentui. After upgrading, while it is failing.

I get the following error:

> Error - [tsc] node_modules/adaptivecards/lib/card-elements.d.ts(907,61): error TS1005: ',' expected.
> Error - [tsc] node_modules/adaptivecards/lib/card-elements.d.ts(907,67): error TS1005: ',' expected.
> Error - [tsc] node_modules/adaptivecards/lib/card-elements.d.ts(908,57): error TS1005: ',' expected.
> Error - [tsc] node_modules/adaptivecards/lib/card-elements.d.ts(908,63): error TS1005: ',' expected.
> Error - [tsc] node_modules/adaptivecards/lib/card-elements.d.ts(932,54): error TS1005: ',' expected.
> Error - [tsc] node_modules/adaptivecards/lib/card-elements.d.ts(932,60): error TS1005: ',' expected.
> Error - [tsc] node_modules/adaptivecards/lib/card-elements.d.ts(933,50): error TS1005: ',' expected.
> Error - [tsc] node_modules/adaptivecards/lib/card-elements.d.ts(933,56): error TS1005: ',' expected.
> Error - 'tsc' sub task errored after 9.14 s
> exited with code 2

Can anyone help me here please.

Comment: Which version are you trying to build? Latest Master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are using the typescript 3.7 (default that was coming with the SPFx before version 1.13). You may need to upgrade it to 3.9 (that is now coming with the latest SPFx version). May be a duplicate of:

[Error - [tsc] node_modules/@fluentui/react/lib/components/ContextualMenu/ContextualMenu.types.d.ts(13,35): error TS1005: ';' expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69852776/error-tsc-node-modules-fluentui-react-lib-components-contextualmenu-context/69868376)